# SQL Server stored procedure: iterate through table, compare values, insert to different table on value change

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, comparison

I can't tell whether my particular situation has already been covered given the titles of other questions, so apologies if an answer already exists.

I have a database that records values as strings, and another table that records runs of particular types within those values.

I require a stored procedure that iterates through the values (I understand this is related to the concept of Cursors), recording each value to temporary tables to control the count for a particular run type (odd/even numbers, for example, or vowels/consonants). When a given value indicates that a particular type of run has stopped (i.e. an odd number has stopped a run of even numbers and vice versa), the run is counted, the count is inserted into a runs table with a related type value (0 = odd/even, 1 = vowel/consonant etc.), the temporary table contents are deleted, and the value that caused the table count/clear is inserted to the temp table.

As I am completely new to stored procedures, I don't know exactly how to structure this kind of procedure, and the examples I've found don't:

- Describe how to implement Cursors in a straightforward, understandable manner
- Provide insights into comparisons between a given value and a stored comparison value
- Allow for recognition of changes to an established pattern to initiate a section of a procedure

Let me know if any of this needs clarifying.

EDIT:

Version in use: MS SQL Server 2012

table structure for the raw values:

```
ID: Int PK AI
DateTimeStamp: Datetime
SelectedValue: Char(2)
UserId: Int
```

table structure for value runs:

```
ID: Int PK AI
DateTimeStamp: Datetime
Type: Int
Run: Int
```

Sample data: [following presented as comma-delimited string for brevity, input by one user]

e, 00, 1, t, r, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, a, i, w, q, u, o, 23, 25, 24, 36, 12, e ...

groups would be:

```
vowels/consonants
even numbers/odd numbers
00
numbers under/over 20
numbers/letters
```

From the above, the runs are:

```
e                (vowels/consonants: vowels)
e                (numbers/letters: letters)
00               (00)
1                (odd/even: odd)
1                (numbers/letters: numbers)
t, r             (vowels/consonants: consonants)
t, r             (numbers/letters: letters)
2, 4             (odd/even: even)
3, 5, 7          (odd/even: odd)
2, 4, 3, 5, 7    (numbers/letters: numbers)
a, i             (vowels/consonants: vowels)
w, q             (vowels/consonants: consonants)
a, i, w, q, u, o (numbers/letters: letters)
1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7 (under/over 20: under 20)
23, 25           (odd/even: odd)
23, 25, 24, 36   (under/over 20: over 20)
24, 36, 12       (odd/even: even)
u, o, e          (vowels/consonants: vowels)
```

Which would make entries to the runs table as

```
Type: vowels/consonants, run: 1
Type: numbers/letters,   run: 1
Type: 00,                run: 1
Type: odd/even,          run: 1
Type: numbers/letters,   run: 1
Type: odd/even,          run: 2
Type: odd/even,          run: 3
Type: numbers/letters,   run: 5
Type: vowels/consonants, run: 2
Type: vowels/consonants, run: 2
Type: numbers/letters,   run: 6
Type: under/over 20,     run: 6
Type: odd/even,          run: 2
Type: under/over 20,     run: 4
Type: odd/even,          run: 3
Type: vowels/consonants, run: 3
```

Comment: showing a table structure for starters...

Comment: and some sample data. And the version of SQL Server that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated based on clarification of the original question.

This might not be the cleanest solution, but it should get you started:

```
WITH cteClassifications (ID, GroupNo, Type, Description) As
(
    -- Vowels:
    SELECT
        ID,
        1,
        1,
        'Vowels'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue In ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

    UNION ALL

    -- Consonants:
    SELECT
        ID,
        1,
        2,
        'Consonants'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        SelectedValue Not In ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

    UNION ALL

    -- Even numbers:
    SELECT
        ID,
        2,
        1,
        'Even numbers'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue != '00'
    And
        SelectedValue Not Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        (TRY_PARSE(SelectedValue As tinyint) & 1) = 0

    UNION ALL

    -- Odd numbers:
    SELECT
        ID,
        2,
        2,
        'Odd numbers'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue != '00'
    And
        SelectedValue Not Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        (TRY_PARSE(SelectedValue As tinyint) & 1) = 1

    UNION ALL

    -- "00":
    SELECT
        ID,
        3,
        1,
        '"00"'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue = '00'

    UNION ALL

    -- Numbers under 20:
    SELECT
        ID,
        4,
        1,
        'Numbers under 20'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue != '00'
    And
        SelectedValue Not Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        TRY_PARSE(SelectedValue As tinyint) < 20

    UNION ALL

    -- Numbers over 20:
    SELECT
        ID,
        4,
        2,
        'Numbers over 20'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue != '00'
    And
        SelectedValue Not Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        TRY_PARSE(SelectedValue As tinyint) > 20

    UNION ALL

    -- Numbers:
    SELECT
        ID,
        5,
        1,
        'Numbers'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue != '00'
    And
        SelectedValue Not Between 'a' And 'z'
    And
        TRY_PARSE(SelectedValue As tinyint) Is Not Null

    UNION ALL

    -- Letters:
    SELECT
        ID,
        5,
        2,
        'Letters'
    FROM
        RawData
    WHERE
        SelectedValue Between 'a' And 'z'
),
cteOrderedClassifications (ID, GroupNo, Type, Description, PrevType, RN) As
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        GroupNo,
        Type,
        Description,
        LAG(Type, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNo ORDER BY ID),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNo ORDER BY ID)
    FROM
        cteClassifications
),
cteGroupedClassifications (ID, GroupNo, Type, Description, RN, ORN) As
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        GroupNo,
        Type,
        Description,
        RN,
        RN
    FROM
        cteOrderedClassifications As C
    WHERE
        Type != PrevType

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        C.ID,
        G.GroupNo,
        G.Type,
        G.Description,
        G.RN,
        C.RN
    FROM
        cteGroupedClassifications As G
        INNER JOIN cteOrderedClassifications As C
        ON C.GroupNo = G.GroupNo
        And C.Type = G.Type
        And C.RN = G.ORN + 1
),
cteRuns (ID, GroupNo, Type, Description, RN, Run) As
(
    SELECT
        Min(ID),
        GroupNo,
        Type,
        MAX(Description),
        RN,
        Count(1)
    FROM
        cteGroupedClassifications
    GROUP BY
        GroupNo,
        Type,
        RN
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) As ID,
    GroupNo,
    Type,
    Description,
    Run
FROM
    cteRuns
ORDER BY
    ID
;
```

Once you're happy that the query is working, you can replace the final `SELECT` with an `INSERT INTO Runs (ID, Type, Run) SELECT ID, Type, Run FROM cteFinalRuns` to populate the table in a single pass.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de031/3)

Comment: The mechanics of the run are that a run is only committed when the contrasting value appears; a run of numbers under 20 is only stopped when a number over 20 occurs, not when a letter occurs. The runs are considered on their own, and not interacting with different types of run. A further note; the nature of the run data is irrelevant. For an odd/even run, it doesn't matter whether the run is comprised of odd numbers or even numbers - only that the run is broken by a contrasting value (even runs broken by an odd number, or odd runs broken by an even number, still produce "odd/even runs").

Comment: @DavidSmithson: OK, I think I see what you're after. I've updated my answer.